# Problem creating levels using inherited classes/polymorphism

Tags: c++, levels, objects, polymorphism

I'm trying to write my level classes by having a base class that each level class inherits from...The base class uses pure virtual functions.

My base class is only going to be used as a vector that'll have the inherited level classes pushed onto it...This is what my code looks like at the moment, I've tried various things and get the same result (segmentation fault).

```
//level.h
class Level
{
  protected:
    Mix_Music *music;
    SDL_Surface *background;
    SDL_Surface *background2;

    vector<Enemy> enemy;

    bool loaded;
    int time;
  public:
    Level();
    virtual ~Level();

    int bgX, bgY;
    int bg2X, bg2Y;
    int width, height;

    virtual void load();
    virtual void unload();

    virtual void update();
    virtual void draw();
};
//level.cpp
Level::Level()
{
  bgX = 0;
  bgY = 0;
  bg2X = 0;
  bg2Y = 0;
  width = 2048;
  height = 480;

  loaded = false;
  time = 0; 
}
Level::~Level()
{
}
//virtual functions are empty...
```

I'm not sure exactly what I'm supposed to include in the inherited class structure, but this is what I have at the moment...

```
//level1.h
class Level1: public Level
{
  public:
    Level1();
   ~Level1();

    void load();
    void unload();

    void update();
    void draw();
};
//level1.cpp
Level1::Level1()
{
}
Level1::~Level1()
{
  enemy.clear();

  Mix_FreeMusic(music);
  SDL_FreeSurface(background);
  SDL_FreeSurface(background2);

  music = NULL;
  background = NULL;
  background2 = NULL;

  Mix_CloseAudio();
}

void Level1::load()
{ 
  music = Mix_LoadMUS("music/song1.xm");
  background = loadImage("image/background.png");
  background2 = loadImage("image/background2.png");

  Mix_OpenAudio(48000, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096);
  Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1); 
}
void Level1::unload()
{
}
//functions have level-specific code in them...
```

Right now for testing purposes, I just have the main loop call Level1 level1; and use the functions, but when I run the game I get a segmentation fault.  This is the first time I've tried writing inherited classes, so I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly.

Comment: Here's a tip about a common C++ rookie mistake you're making. Since you intend to use polymorphism, mark `~Level()` as virtual too or you will get into problems when trying to call `delete` on a `Level*` pointer.

Comment: Did you mean to NULL out your pointers in Level1::~Level1 before calling their free functions?

Comment: I didn't mean to...But I already fixed it and I still have the same problem.

Comment: What are the "functions have level-specific code in them..."? if the code is just as it is in the question, you doesnt really need to use polymorphism.

Comment: Ah on your destructor, it seems that every child of Level will have a exactly equal destructor, so, i think that would be easier to put that code in the base.

Comment: This seems... really over-designed. Why do you need to have a new class for each level? That will make it really hard and annoying to add more levels in the future. Ideally, you should have a single level class that can handle loading a variety of different levels.

Comment: The functions are load(), unload(), etc with code for the level written in them.  As for the destructor, would I still want to have it virtual if I just use it in the base class?

Comment: @thedaian That was going to be my plan B if I couldn't figure this out...I just figured it'd be easier to manage each level if I had them in their own class.

Comment: @Adam Easier to think, but it will require a lot more work.

Comment: Well, I figured out why I was getting a segmentation fault...It was actually because I was trying to load the music before calling Mix_OpenAudio and had nothing to do with the inheritance...I had moved Mix_OpenAudio there because I was reorganizing my code and just kind of forgot about it, so it seemed like the segmentation fault was because of the inheritance.  But...Waste of time because I'm going to take your advice and just manage the levels in a single class using level states to check what to do.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. Making a class for each level? No, levels are **data**, not code. Make a generic `Level` class, and then load `.level` (or whatever) files into it. The files then should just have a list of all the resources that need to be loaded, a list of events/scripts, and so on.

Why? Because then you can make a separate level editor, that creates the `.level` files for you, and you don't even have to touch your game's code (which generates bugs and so on).

Classes are here to group similar behaviors and data (objects) together, creating a new class for each instance of an object is illogical and defies the very purpose of classes.

Comment: I actually disagree. For a large scale game engine you may be able to put everything into scripts that run based off of triggers but for a small game it may be easier to simply make each level a class that has special coding especially if you want each level to do drastically different things.

Comment: First, that's a pretty bad practice. Just because you *can* do it, doesn't mean you should. What if you want to scale up your game? Add another 20 levels? There are even simpler ways of making the levels drastically different, for example, just including function-pointers in a vector, and then executing them when needed...